# Creating a relationship between tables and creating a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

How to make relation between these tables?

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `position` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `pm` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user1read` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `user2read` varchar(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `parent` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `authorid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`id2`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` text NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: There is a tutorial here : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

Comment: we have no idea what relationships you want...

Comment: this is database for forum...

Answer (score 0):

If a **`topics`** has a **`users`** as an author,

if you are storing the `id` value of the **`users`** that is the author of the **`topics`** in the `authorid` column,

The "author" relationship is a one-to-many relationship. A `topics` is related to one (or zero) **`users`**. (And a **`users`** can be the "author" of zero, one or more **`topics`**.)

Here's an example of a foreign key definition to have the database (InnoDB storage engine) enforce the integrity of that relationship:

```
ALTER TABLE topics 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_topics_users_author
  FOREIGN KEY (authorid) REFERENCES users (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```